How to setup Slurm to encourage efficient HPC use?
I'm currently setting up Slurm to use across researchers, and I want to fix the problem of inefficient allocation. I need advice on configuring  Slurm better to encourage this.
Here's my summary of high-level issues I've seen when sharing compute in Google, OpenAI, Meta, and various startups. (my current startup uses Slurm)
In our current system, we have 1 queue, and users end up using machines for low-value jobs because they have no personal penalty for using machines. Meanwhile high-value jobs are stuck pending.
I could use multiple queues queues, but this requires me to play the role of program manager, and carefully think about about allocating priorities/machines properly.
Ideally, I want a system where users are incentivized to useless jobs early, because it gives them some benefit, ie, improved priority in scheduling next job. Any tips?

It sounds like you want to tune the "fair share" aspect of slurm's multifactor priority queue. This will prevent one user/group of users from hogging the queue (unless they were allocated a large portion of the available time). Users can also manually add a "nice" value to de-prioritize their jobs, but from the users perspective their job is always top priority and there's no incentive (other than fairshare or external factors) to get users to be nice.

Unfortunately the judgement call of whether a job is low or high value is a management decision, so someone in management will have to balance allocating resources between users. A sysadmin can manually remove jobs and/or submit certain jobs with extra high priority if requested, so that can solve the issue of "the system is currently filled with low value jobs and I need some high value jobs run now", while during normal usage system utilization is maximized, even if it is utilized for less valuable jobs.
